# Cannot find modue default firebase app

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
const credentials = require('./credentials.json');
const db = admin.firestore();

const user = require('./http-functions/user-creation')

var config = {
  apiKey: "KEY",
  authDomain: "ecommerce.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://ecommerce.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "ecommerce",
  storageBucket: "ecommerce.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "ID"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config)

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(credentials),
  databaseURL: "https://ecommerce.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "ecommerce"
});

exports.addUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => user.addUser(req, res, db, firebase))
```

I'm importing firebase so that I can use the firebase.auth() to create a new user on cloud functions firestore. But I'm having this error where it says that when I run my firebase deploy:

> Error: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.
>       at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor]

Below is the code for adding a new user

```
   module.exports = {
  addUser: function(req, res, db, firebase, admin) {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailandPassword(email, password)
            .then(userRecord => {
              const uid = userRecord.uid;
              const email = userRecord.email;
              return firebase.firestore()
              .collection('users')
              .doc(uid)
              .set({email: email},
                  {merge: true});
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err)
            })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the `intitializeApp` into a const and use it instead of `firebase.auth()`

Something like:

```
var config = {
  apiKey: "KEY",
  authDomain: "ecommerce.firebaseapp.com",
  ...
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config)

module.exports = {
  addUser: function(req, res, db, firebase, admin) {
    firebaseApp.auth().createUserWithEmailandPassword(email, password)
     ...
  }
}
```

Comment: It says that firebaseApp.auth() is not a function